# How to add a AWS public extension to a AWS Lambda cloud formation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I want to add the 'AWS-Parameters-and-Secrets-Lambda-Extension' public extension to the cloud formation template of my AWS Lambda function.

Everything I found so far adds the public extension either by i) the AWS lambda console or ii) the AWS cli. The cloud formation doc itself states that the AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion only allows to create lambda layers from a zip archive. I've also tried to export the cloud formation template of a function where I've added the extension using the AWS Lambda console, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

How do I add this extension to cloud formation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layer is part of AWS::Lambda::Function, see the doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-layers).

Then the layer ARN depending on the region you want to deploy your lambda. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ps-integration-lambda-extensions.html#ps-integration-lambda-extensions-add) is the list based on the region.

Something like this for `eu-west-1`:

```
Resources:
  Function:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/lambda-role
      Layers:
        - arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:015030872274:layer:AWS-Parameters-and-Secrets-Lambda-Extension:4
      Code:
        S3Bucket: my-bucket
        S3Key: function.zip
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Timeout: 5
      TracingConfig:
        Mode: Active
```